# Input bluetooth password automatically using codes

Tags: android, bluetooth

We're using arduino bluetooth module in our project. It will connect to our android device. Since the project target blind people, we need to have a "less input" enviroment. One our problems is the Bluetooth passkey. The android device use an application using Processing IDE to connect to arduino. Does it have a code which will automatically input password when the password notification bar appears?[image]

Comment: Has the phone been paired with the phone?

Comment: Our project process for first time users so the bluetooth device has not bern paired to the phone :)